# Jenkins SSH server showing error Algorithm negotiation fail while trying to setup with over the SSH plugin

Tags: jenkins, ssh, sshd

Jenkins SSH server showing mentioned error **Algorithm negotiation fail** while trying to set up with **over the SSH plugin** when trying to connect over ssh to a local server (Linux Container). I am able to connect using ssh on the terminal.

*jenkins.plugins.publish_over.BapPublisherException: Failed to connect and initialize SSH connection. Message: [Failed to connect session for config [anisbleHOST]. Message [Algorithm negotiation fail]]*

Ubuntu machine - auth.log
*Unable to negotiate with xx.xx.xx.x port 39866: no matching host key type found. Their offer: ssh-rsa,ssh-dss,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521 [preauth]*

tried with the mentioned below sshd_config values but no luck.

**HostKeyAlgorithms** ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519

**KexAlgorithms** curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To resolve the above-mentioned issue first I made changes to /etc/ssh/sshd_config and regenerated RSA keys using ssh-keygen. Jenkins doesn't support keys generated using ed25519.

### **My New sshd_config -**

HostKeyAlgorithms ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa

HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_key

HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key

HostCertificate /etc/ssh/ssh_host_key-cert.pub

KexAlgorithms diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384

PubkeyAcceptedKeyTypes  ssh-rsa,ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519

TrustedUserCAkeys /etc/ssh/ssh_user_ca.pub

PasswordAuthentication no

ChallengeResponseAuthentication no

UsePAM yes

PrintMotd no

AcceptEnv LANG LC_*

Subsystem       sftp    /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server

LogLevel DEBUG

---

Please UPVOTE if it helps you :)